# jQuery tabs cookie persistance with ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two sets of tabs, one nested inside the other. The nested tabs get reloaded by a setInterval that refreshes all of the content. On page load, the cookie for those nested tabs gets set fine, but once the refresh happens, it goes away and the selected tab just jumps back to the first. Here's an image of what it looks like: http://screencast.com/t/nAZlNXIBe 
So when I am under the Assigned tab, and click the Normal tab, I'd expect it to stay on the Normal tab when the setInterval kicks in and refreshes those tabs. Here's the code I'm using:

```
var $tabs2  = $('#nested').tabs({ cookie: { expires: 1, name: "nested_tabs" } });
setInterval(function() {
  $('#tabs-1 .content').load('/dashboard/mine'); 
}, 30000);
```

This code basically just sets the tabs and the cookie, then the refresh happens to populate that whole area, including the tabs. Would it be breaking because the tabs are being reloaded with the ajax as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, here's the code:

```
var $tabs2  = $('#nested').tabs();
$tabs2.bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
  $.cookie('nested_tabs', ui.index);
});
setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({   url: '/dashboard/mine',   success: function(html){
    $tabs2.tabs("destroy");
    $('#tabs-1 .content').html(html);
    $tabs2  = $('#nested').tabs({ selected: $.cookie('nested_tabs') });
    $tabs2.bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
      $.cookie('nested_tabs', ui.index);
    });  
  }          
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cookie expires in 1ms, change that.

If your not already doing so, you might need to load that [cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), it goes right before your jquery-ui file.

you can try:

```
var $tabs2  = $('#nested').tabs({ cookie: { expires: 30000, name: "nested_tabs" } });
 setInterval(function() {     
         $.ajax({   url: '/dashboard/mine',   success: function(html){
            $tabs2.tabs("destroy");
            $('#tabs-1 .content').html(html);
            $tabs2  = $('#nested').tabs({ cookie: { expires: 30000, name: "nested_tabs" } });   }          
         });  
    }, 30000);
```

but I doubt destroying reloading and rebuilding the tabs every 30 seconds would be good for cpu/bandwidth/ux...

Comment: I do have the cookie plugin, and i've tried 1, 30000, 3000000 just to be sure. It looks like since the sub tabs(content) is being refreshed with ajax, that the .tabs() call isn't persisting down, here's what it's looking like [after the refresh](http://screencast.com/t/KpOJF1v0ixm)

Comment: This is an internal app so the bandwidth isn't that important, it'll only be used by like 6 people. However, the cookie is still getting deleted when the content is refreshed. Would there be a way to make the cookie a global var and then just set the cookie from that var? I know globals are bad but that's really the only thing I see. Unless I can .bind/.live it somehow to persist

Comment: I've changed the code so the cookie doesn't expire for 30 seconds, which is the same as the refresh rate... hope it helps

Comment: Nope, cookie still isn't persisting past the refresh. I've even made it 31 seconds to see if it would make a difference :(

Comment: Also, the cookie plugin you linked to above doesn't work with jQuery UI 1.8.18 so i'm using [this one](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) Do you think that would be an issue?

Comment: I'm not sure if they're interchangeable, I doubt it, but the doc says to use the carhartl jquery-cookie plugin...